# Laravel macros not autoloading

Tags: laravel-4

I have the following directory structure

```
app
|   ...
|   lib
|   |   Macro.php
|   |   Events.php
|   ...
```

In my `composer.json` I have

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": {
        ...
        "app/lib"
        ...
    }
}
```

`Events.php` loads fine and updates the DB when the event triggers:

```
<?php

Event::listen('auth.login', function($user) {

    $user->last_login = new DateTime;
    $user->save();

});
```

`Macros.php` will always return the error `Method messageBox does not exist` if the macro is used in a view:

```
<?php

Form::macro('test', function()
{
    return 'test';
});
```

I have run `composer dump-autoload`. Why is the `Macros.php` not autoloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoload `classmap` section in composer.json maps excatly that: classes. So it won't help you in this instance, because you don't have a class declaration in that file. You can however autoload `files` as well with composer, by adding this to the autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
       ...
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/lib/Macros.php"
    ]
}
```

As an alternative you could always manually include the file in Laravel's `app/start/global.php` like so:

```
require app_path() . '/lib/Macros.php';
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a great tip about autoloading files. I'm still not understanding why `Event::listen` works and `Form::macro` doesn't. Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't they both calling static methods of their facade?

Comment: I've tried simulating your scenario on a clean Laravel install and neither the Event or the Macro work unless the file is loaded beforehand, which is to be expected (so I don't know how it could be working in your case, without explicitly including the `Events.php` file in some way or another). I've also noticed that my first suggestion about using composer autoload files (while a valid way to autoload) doesn't work in this case because it includes the code before the Facades are being aliased and it throws Class not found error. The only way it worked was to include the files in `global.php`.

Comment: You're 100% right. I just tried the same and got exactly the same result. `last_login` is being updated because I recently switched from `zizaco/Confide` to `cartalyst/Sentry` and the mechanism is somewhere else. I guess that `last_login` wasn't being recorded in the old system and I'd just never noticed.